# Can't use "static" keyword on a static method in a c++ class implementation file (.cpp)

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

Consider:

// In Vector2.h

```
class Vector2
{
    public:
        // returns the degrees in radians
        static double calcDir(double x, double y);
}
```

// In Vector2.cpp

```
double Vector2::calcDir(double x, double y)
{
    double rad = ...;
    return rad;
}
```

Why isn't the keyword **static** required in the signature in Vector2.cpp?  When I try this, it produces an error:

```
static double Vector2::calcDir(double x, double y)
```

It seems inconsistent to me.  All other parts of the method signature are required to be repeated in the .cpp file (return type, method name (duh), names and types of args, const-ness). I don't like not knowing at a glance whether a method is static or not (when looking at the implementation).

Is there a reason this is not only not required, but forbidden?

Comment: I think this falls under "because the standard says so". Same goes for `virtual`, by the way.

Comment: `virtual` is not required to be repeated as well. Only things that take part in overload resolution (and the return type) have to be repeated.

Comment: @Nathan Ernst: I never realised the standard wrote itself.

Comment: *I don't like not knowing at a glance if a method is static or not* - I avoid this by using different cases: `Static()` and `instance()`

Comment: I use comments. `/*static*/ class::double blabla()`. Same for arguments with default values. `class:fun x(y = 0)` isn't allowed in the defintion either, so I write `class::fun x(y /*= 0*/)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because `static` has a special meaning when used in a class definition. In a class definition it identifies the function as a static member function which means it doesn't operate on a class instance but can be called independently.

Outside of a class `static` gives a function internal linkage but this is illegal on (even static) member functions because class members must have the same linkage as the class of which they are a member (almost always external, and certainly external in cases where you can defined member functions outside of the class definition).

From a language point of view, the declaration of members inside a class definition follows one set of language rules where `static` has its special class meaning. Outside of a class definition, all function definitions - members and non-members - follow the same set of rules where `static` has it's other meaning which is not valid for members of classes with external linkage.

Comment: Is "use internal linkage" sometimes colloquially referred to as "file static"? I thought it might have something to do with that.

Comment: @SamuelMeacham: Yes, "file static" is sometimes used instead of "with internal linkage".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably to reduce confusion. At file scope, 'the keyword *static* is (confusingly) used to mean "use internal linkage" (TC++PL p.200). It could imply that the function, though a member of a class, was only visible inside the current translation unit. Allowing the static specifier there would be more confusing.

Note that using *static* to denote internal linkage is no longer recommended, and that anonymous namespaces should be preferred to achieve that.

Comment: Entities declared in anonymous namespaces do not get internal linkage unless they are also declared static, they just get translation unit specific names. </pedantry>

Comment: Is there any reason for anonymous namespaces being preferred over static for internal linkage?  Also Charles' comment is interesting, that static is still required if you actually want internal linkage.  @CharlesBailey, with the translation unit specific names, do you still get the same end result as with internal linkage?  Meaning, do people realize that by not using static they aren't getting internal linkage, but don't care?  It's been a while since I've used c++ daily (I work with c#), but I have a deep love for this language and want to get back in the game =)

Comment: There's effectively no difference that I know of, hence "</pedantry>". The standard has a note: "Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit."

Answer (score 1):

It is annoying that keyword wound up invoking two very different functionalities (global-to-all-class-instances vs. local-to-file) but the following small header may be of use.  The macro just expands to an empty string meaning you can tack it in front of the declarations of methods in the implementation file and coming back to your code a year later you'll avoid pouring through a 2000-line "boost-esque" header to find out why the compiler won't let you use this.

staticmethod.h:

```
/*
** macro sugar for maintaining readability
** of static methods in implementation files
*/
#ifndef STATICMETHOD
#define STATICMETHOD
```

In your .cpp files you could then use:

```
#include "staticmethod.h"
STATICMETHOD double Vector2::calcDir(double x, double y)
{
    double rad = ...;
    return rad;
}
```